# GCC switches to enable analysis for warnings

Tags: debugging, gcc, compiler-construction, warnings

In GCC, certain warnings require optimization to be enabled. For example:

```
int foo() {
    int x;
    return x;
}
```

In order to detect the uninitialized variable, *-O* must be passed.

```
$ gcc -W -Wall -c test.c
$ gcc -W -Wall -c test.c -O
```

```
test.c: In function ‘foo’:
test.c:3: warning: ‘x’ is used uninitialized in this function
```

However, this can interfere with debugging. Is there a way to enable just the analysis phases needed for warnings (and not just this particular warning, but as many as possible), without affecting the generated code too much?

I'm using GCC version 4.3.3 (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) on x86-64.

Comment: The silly answer would be to compile it with -O for the warnings, and then without it for debugging. I really hope there is a better way though.

Comment: The reason gcc doesn't issue that warning without -O is that it doesn't do data-flow analysis without -O. So you're asking it to do the DFA, but discard the results other than using them to issue warnings. This would take about as long as compiling with -O, although hopefully not as long as Zifre's suggestion. But I don't know of any way to make gcc do it, and the man page implies it is impossible.

Comment: -O is fast enough, I'm just hoping it won't muck up debugging. Suggestions on how to enable specific optimization phases that won't break gdb, but will perform warning analysis are welcome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`-Wall`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall) instead of `-W`. `-W` is deprecated IIRC. (As Jonathan Leffler points out in a comment, `-W`'s replacement is [`-Wextra`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra), not `-Wall`.)

> [`-Wunused-variable`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunknown-pragmas#index-Wunused-variable) 
> Warn whenever a local variable or non-constant static variable is unused aside from its declaration. This warning is enabled by `-Wall`.

*[3.8 Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)*

This behavior has [changed in GCC 4.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html):

> Uninitialized warnings do not require enabling optimization anymore, that is, `-Wuninitialized` can be used together with `-O0`. Nonetheless, the warnings given by `-Wuninitialized` will probably be more accurate if optimization is enabled.

Comment: As shown in my example above, passing -W -Wall is insufficient to perform dataflow analysis with optimization disabled

Comment: I don't have this problem. Whenever I use -Wall, I get the warning (but not with -W). Which GCC version are you using?

Comment: Added my gcc version to the question.

Comment: FWIW, I get the same result as bdonlan on gcc 3.4.4 on cygwin 32bit. No warning without an optimization level of 1 or more.

Comment: @Bastien: aha - you changed the code. You made x completely unreferenced, and got the unused variable warning. bdonlan is after the uninitialized warning.

Comment: Got it, it's new in 4.4. See here, under the title “C family”: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html.

Comment: @onebyone: luckily, the same thing seems to apply to both warnings. But I really need to sleep...

Comment: Nah, you get the unused variable warning without -O since forever, since that doesn't require DFA, just flagging each variable. Congratulations: you're psychic to have known that 4.4 is different for uninitialized, without actually provoking that warning :-)

Comment: -W is deprecated; its replacement is -Wextra, though, not -Wall.

Comment: Removed the command-line session, since it's useless to the PO. Added some information provided in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

[DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Display_Debugger) and GDB can mostly cope with code compiled with `gcc -O -g`.  Sometimes variables aren't in scope when you expect them to be, but DDD is clever enough to say "optimized away" instead of freaking out.  But there's no question it's easier to debug with -O turned off—I have seen this a lot with my students' code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have your automated build for. Let your automated build engine build with -Werror -Wall -O2, and you'll catch all the warnings triggered by higher optimization levels.

Comment: A system such as Hudson is *really* easy to setup and configure, you can without problem use it even for small hobby projects.